# Parse Text File after a specific word VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, parsing, text, .net

I have a Module Application that reads a text file and finds lines with specific words in them .

My input looks something like this

```
 Dealer Number: 90402001
 Dealer Name: SAN TAN FORD     
 Contract Number: 7466564   
 OverRide Class:       
 Contract Code: 3417620
 Portal Claim#: 148905

 Dealer Number: 90402001
 Dealer Name: SAN TAN FORD     
 Contract Number: 7679454   
 OverRide Class:       
 Contract Code: 3762406
 Portal Claim#: 149325

 Dealer Number: 90416003
 Dealer Name: CAR TOWN KIA     
 Contract Number: DG209507  
 OverRide Class:       
 Contract Code: 3110169
 Portal Claim#: 134550

 Dealer Number: 90430005
 Dealer Name: RICH FORD     
 Contract Number: 7380708   
 OverRide Class:       
 Contract Code: 3130744
 Portal Claim#: 148537
```

My output is as below

```
 Dealer Name: SAN TAN FORD     Contract Number: 7466564
 Dealer Name: SAN TAN FORD     Contract Number: 7679454
 Dealer Name: RICH FORD        Contract Number: 7380708
```

All i need to do now is grab the text after "Number:"

Here is what i have so far

```
 Imports System.IO

 Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim str
    Dim fileName = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\textfile.txt"

    Dim lines() = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)

    For i = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If lines(i).Contains("SAN TAN FORD") Then
            Str = String.Format("{0}{1}", lines(i), lines(i + 1))
            Console.WriteLine(str)
        ElseIf lines(i).Contains("RICH FORD") Then
            Str = String.Format("{0}{1}", lines(i), lines(i + 1))
            Console.WriteLine(str)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

 End Module
```

Im thinking there is something like a lines.after? So it would be something like

```
 text = lines(i).after("Number:")
 Console.writeline(text)
```

And that would give me

```
 7466564
 7679454
 7380708
```

Ideas?

Comment: I'm slightly confused - what do you want your final output to be (in total)?

Comment: My output would be what i want the module to give me. 7466564 etc...
Why was my question down voted, i thought i was extremely specific.

Comment: I don't know why... Wasn't me :( - Glad you got your solution, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways of doing something like this.  You can use `IndexOf` and `SubString` to find and extract the portion of the string that you want.  You could use the `Regex` class to find and read the matching value, or, probably most simply, you could just use the `Split` method.  If you consider the string `"Number: "` to be a delimiter between two other strings, then you can use `Split` to get the strings before and after that delimiter.  So, for instance:

```
Dim input As String = "Contract Number: 7380708"
Dim parts() As String = input.Split("Number: ")
Console.WriteLine(parts(0))  ' Outputs "Contract "
Console.WriteLine(parts(1))  ' Outputs "7380708"
```

Comment: Awesome, i knew about split, but i didn't know you could index it like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "after" function but you can do something similar with split or indexof

```
    Dim input, output As String

    input = "Contract Number: 7466564"

    ' With trim
    output = input.Split(":")(1).Trim()
    Console.WriteLine(output)

    ' With index of
    output = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("Contract Number:") + "Contract Number:".Length).Trim()
    Console.WriteLine(output)
```